# 2D array code and method not working

Tags: java, arrays, methods, syntax

the code should create a 2d array, with different spaces. I think the array works, but now my methods dont. when trying to run it an illegal start of expression error and a ";" expected. The first method is void, because it doesnt return anything. I get the illegal start of expression in almost every method. Thanks for your help. The language im using is Java. The errors show up on lines 125, 190, 267 and 345.

```
   public class Clinica { 
   public static void main(String[] args){


    Guardia[][] horario = new Guardia[10][31];
    horario[0] = new Guardia [31];      
    horario[1] = new Guardia [28];
    horario[2] = new Guardia [31];
    horario[3] = new Guardia [30];
    horario[4] = new Guardia [31];
    horario[5] = new Guardia [30];
    horario[6] = new Guardia [31];
    horario[7] = new Guardia [31];
    horario[8] = new Guardia [30];
    horario[9] = new Guardia [31];
    horario[10] = new Guardia [30];
    horario[11] = new Guardia [31];


    Medico[] lm = new Medico[5];

    Enfermera[] le = new Enfermera[5];

    lm[0]= new Medico();
    lm[0].setNombre("Juan Perez");
    lm[0].setNit(67996523l);
    lm[0].setDpi(1234567870101l);
    lm[0].setColegiado(89098);
    lm[0].setSalario(15000);
    lm[0].setEspecialista("si");



    lm[1]= new Medico();
    lm[1].setNombre("Luis Gutierrez");
    lm[1].setNit(89645473l);
    lm[1].setDpi(9876543260101l);
    lm[1].setColegiado(98554);
    lm[1].setSalario(12000);
    lm[1].setEspecialista("no");

    lm[2]= new Medico();
    lm[2].setNombre("Eduardo Gonzalez");
    lm[2].setNit(87864566l);
    lm[2].setDpi(5642871750101l);
    lm[2].setColegiado(5653);
    lm[2].setSalario(1700);
    lm[2].setEspecialista("si");

    lm[3]= new Medico();
    lm[3].setNombre("Guadalupe Torres");
    lm[3].setNit(56848731l);
    lm[3].setDpi(4562973920101l);
    lm[3].setColegiado(5653);
    lm[3].setSalario(17000);
    lm[3].setEspecialista("si");

    lm[4]= new Medico();
    lm[4].setNombre("Maria Castillo");
    lm[4].setNit(87654857l);
    lm[4].setDpi(569395290101l);
    lm[4].setColegiado(67955);
    lm[4].setSalario(13000);
    lm[4].setEspecialista("no");

    le[0]= new Enfermera();
    le[0].setNombre1("Juana Lopez");
    le[0].setNit1(5632691l);
    le[0].setDpi1(5643213450101l);
    le[0].setIntensivista("no");
    le[0].setSalario1(6000);

    le[1]= new Enfermera();
    le[1].setNombre1("Lidia Mendez");
    le[1].setNit1(76543766l);
    le[1].setDpi1(1246547850101l);
    le[1].setIntensivista("si");
    le[1].setSalario1(9000);

    le[2]= new Enfermera();
    le[2].setNombre1("Miriam Garcia");
    le[2].setNit1(98764568l);
    le[2].setDpi1(6547854370101l);
    le[2].setIntensivista("no");
    le[2].setSalario1(8000);

    le[3]= new Enfermera();
    le[3].setNombre1("Lorna Suarez");
    le[3].setNit1(45678658l);
    le[3].setDpi1(569374160101l);
    le[3].setIntensivista("si");
    le[3].setSalario1(10000);

    le[4]= new Enfermera();
    le[4].setNombre1("Mariela Rodriguez");
    le[4].setNit1(67896548l);
    le[4].setDpi1(3254786540101l);
    le[4].setIntensivista("no");
    le[4].setSalario1(8000);


    //Random rand = new Random(); 
    //int a = rand.nextInt(1)+vm;
    lenm=lm.length;
    lene=le.length;

    int nm =rand(0-lenm);
    int ne =rand(0-lene);

    for(int i=0; i<horario.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<horario[i].length; j++){
            medt=lm[nm];
            enft=le[ne];
            horario[i][j]=new Guardia(medt, enft);
        }
    }

    public void Cambiar(int dpi, int mes, int dia){
        int DPI=dpi;
        int MES=mes;
        int DIA=dia;


        int x1=0;
        int x2=0;
        int x3=0;
        int x4=0;
        int x5=0;
        x1=lm[0].getDpi
        x2=lm[1].getDpi
        x3=lm[2].getDpi
        x4=lm[3].getDpi
        x5=lm[4].getDpi


        if(DPI==x1){
            horario[MES][DIA].setNombre("Juan Perez");
            horario[MES][DIA].setNit(67996523);
            horario[MES][DIA].setDpi(1234567870101);
            horario[MES][DIA].setColegiado(89098);
            horario[MES][DIA].setSalario(15000.00);
            horario[MES][DIA].setEspecialista("si");
        }else{
            if(DPI==x2){
                horario[MES][DIA].setNombre("Luis Gutierrez");
                horario[MES][DIA].setNit(89645473);
                horario[MES][DIA].setDpi(9876543260101);
                horario[MES][DIA].setColegiado(98554);
                horario[MES][DIA].setSalario(12000.00);
                horario[MES][DIA].setEspecialista("no");
            }else{
                if(DPI==x30){
                    horario[MES][DIA].setNombre("Eduardo Gonzalez");
                    horario[MES][DIA].setNit(87864566);
                    horario[MES][DIA].setDpi(5642871750101);
                    horario[MES][DIA].setColegiado(5653);
                    horario[MES][DIA].setSalario(1700.00);
                    horario[MES][DIA].setEspecialista("si");
                }else{
                    if(DPI==x4){
                        horario[MES][DIA].setNombre("Guadalupe Torres");
                        horario[MES][DIA].setNit(56848731);
                        horario[MES][DIA].setDpi(4562973920101);
                        horario[MES][DIA].setColegiado(5653);
                        horario[MES][DIA].setSalario(17000.00);
                        horario[MES][DIA].setEspecialista("si");
                    }else{
                        if(DPI==x5){
                            horario[MES][DIA].setNombre("Maria Castillo");
                            horario[MES][DIA].setNit(87654857);
                            horario[MES][DIA].setDpi(569395290101);
                            horario[MES][DIA].setColegiado(67955);
                            horario[MES][DIA].setSalario(13000.00);
                            horario[MES][DIA].setEspecialista("no");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public String MayoriaGuardia(){

        for(int i=0; i<horario.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<horario[i].length; j++){
                String nom="";
                String nom1="";
                int j=0;
                int l=0;
                int e=0;
                int g=0;
                int m=0;

                nom=horario[i][j].getNombre;
                nom1=nom.toLowerCase;
                if(nom=="juan perez"){
                    j=j+1;
                }else{
                if(nom=="luis gutierrez"){
                        l=l+1;
                    }else{
                        if(nom=="eduardo gonzalez"){
                            e=e+1;
                        }else{
                            if(nom=="guadalupe torres"){
                                g=g+1;
                            }else{
                                if(nom=="maria castillo"){
                                m=m+1;
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }       
        }


        String ma="";
        int totj=0;
        int totl=0;
        int tote=0;
        int totg=0;
        int totm=0;


        if(j>l && j>e && j>g && j>m){
            totj=(j-2)*900;
            ma="Juan Perez tuvo guardia "+j+" veces, y tiene un monto extra de: Q"+totj;
        }else{
            if(l>j && l>e && l>g && l>m){
                totl=(l-2)*900;
                ma="Luis Gutierrez tuvo guardia "+l+" veces, y tiene un monto extra de: Q"+totl;
            }else{
                if(e>l && e>j && e>g && e>m){
                    tote=(e-2)*900;
                    ma="Eduardo Gonzalez tuvo guardia "+e+" veces, y tiene un monto extra de: Q"+tote;
                }else{
                    if(g>l && g>j && g>g && g>m){
                        totg=(g-2)*900;
                        ma="Guadalupe Torres tuvo guardia "+g+" veces, y tiene un monto extra de: Q"+totg;
                    }else{
                        if(m>l && m>j && m>g && m>e){
                            totm=(m-2)*900;
                            ma="Maria Castillo tuvo guardia "+m+" veces, y tiene un monto extra de: Q"+totm;        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ma;  
    }





    public int TotalAdicional(){
        for(int i=0; i<horario.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<horario[i].length; j++){
                String nom1="";
                String nom11="";
                int j1=0;
                int l1=0;
                int e1=0;
                int g1=0;
                int m1=0;

                nom1=horario[i][j].getNombre;
                nom11=nom1.toLowerCase;
                if(nom11=="juan perez"){
                    j1=j1+1;
                }else{
                if(nom11=="luis gutierrez"){
                        l1=l1+1;
                    }else{
                        if(nom11=="eduardo gonzalez"){
                            e1=e1+1;
                        }else{
                            if(nom11=="guadalupe torres"){
                                g1=g1+1;
                            }else{
                                if(nom11=="maria castillo"){
                                m1=m1+1;
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }   

        for(int i=0; i<horario.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<horario[i].length; j++){         
                String nom2="";
                String nom22="";
                int j12=0;
                int l12=0;
                int e12=0;
                int g12=0;
                int m12=0;

                nom2=horario[i][j].getNombre1;
                nom22=nom2.toLowerCase;
                if(nom22=="juana lopez"){
                    j12=j12+1;
                }else{
                if(nom22=="lidia mendez"){
                        l12=l12+1;
                    }else{
                        if(nom22=="miriam garcia"){
                            e12=e12+1;
                        }else{
                            if(nom22=="lorna suarez"){
                                g12=g12+1;
                            }else{
                                if(nom22=="mariela rodriguez"){
                                m12=m12+1;
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }       
        }

        int totala=0;
        totala=(((j-2)+(l-2)+(g-2)+(e-2)+(m-2))*900)+(((j12-4)+(l12-4)+(g12-4)+(e12-4)+(m12-4))*500)
        return totala;
    }





    public int VecesJuntos(int nit1, int nit2){
        int NITM=nit;
        int NITE=nit2;
        int NITML=0;
        int NITEL=0;
        int cuenta=0;

        NITML=horario[i][j].getNit;
        NITEL=horario[i][j].getNit1;
        for(int i=0; i<horario.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<horario[i].length; j++){
                if(NITML==NITM && NITEL==NITE){
                    cuenta=cuenta+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return cuenta;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add what language you're using and what lines the errors show up on. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: done, sorry, im new to the page

Answer (score 2):

This whole section is missing semicolons:

```
    x1=lm[0].getDpi
    x2=lm[1].getDpi
    x3=lm[2].getDpi
    x4=lm[3].getDpi
    x5=lm[4].getDpi
```

Where is `getDpi` defined anyway? If that's a method call -I assume it is- that should be closed as such, i.e. `getDpi();`

Comment: thats a 1d array, just to create a array of objects